# How to solve the python error when open function path contains a "?"

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, path

The following is the error code

```
    savePath = "E:\\Desktop\\output\\?.html"
    file = open(savePath, 'wb')
```

After running the error message is as follows：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Main.py", line 35, in
<module>
     crawler.testSaveContent("E:\\Desktop\\output\\?.html")   File 
"E:\Desktop\MyCrawler.py", line 77, in testSaveContent
     file = open(savePath, 'wb') OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 
'E:\\Desktop\\output\\?.html'
```

my python version is 3.6.3

Comment: Install linux. Or something else that isn't Windows. Alternatively, accept the fact that a file name can't contain a question mark.

Comment: Look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names).

Comment: @Aran-Fey thank you very much. I understand

Comment: @zipa The instructions are detailed and I understand. thank you very much for your help